# how can i put 0 leading in a number with decimals?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i put 0 leading in a number with decimals?

for example when i have this number

```
.7967 => 0.7967
```

but i want a regex for the **first case**

Comment: You can only do that by converting the number to a string for display purposes since the integral part of a number can't start with zero. --> `"0" + yourNumber`

Comment: @ScottMarcus i want to put a zero .7967 => 0.7967

Comment: @ScottMarcus It can, but JS will treat it as Octal :)

Comment: Yes, I know. Same answer.

Comment: `.7867` is `0.7867` in JS...? Oh, you mean in a string?

Comment: @NullDev Yes, and to avoid that, you need my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) for this:

```
parseFloat('.7967').toString();
//0.7967

parseFloat('067.7967').toString();
//67.7967
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regex on a number string do this:

```
'.7967'.replace(/^\./, '0.')
// return: '0.7967'

'1.7967'.replace(/^\./, '0.')
// return: '1.7967' (unchanged)
```